# How to Securely store application private files?

Tags: android, encryption, android-file

After reading some articles & threads on stackoverflow. I found out that even files stored with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` can be read after rooting the device.

Then what are the options I have to store a file privately, which are only readable to my app.

Is encryption is only option I have ? I will keep file encrypted & only my app knows how to decrypt.

Does android platform provides any other mechanism for this purpose ?

Comment: You'll probably need to encrypt the data. I'd say make the same assumption you would if it were a client-side JS app: assume the client will have full access to the data.

Comment: `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` just prevents other apps from reading it and use it. That means, I can access other apps entries that are `WORLD_READABLE` . That makes sense if I want to share entries to other apps that can use them. But rooted devices have access to everywhere. Use encryption, but You can´t be sure that such private data isn´t cracked.No matter what anybody says, at the end NOTHING....I mean absolutely NOTHING is secure. There will allways be a way to hack, you just can make it harder to do so.

Comment: "what are the options I have to store a file privately" -- keep it on a server and never store it on the device. In fact, since people might hack into your server: unplug the server, put the server in a safe, drop the safe into the Marianas Trench in the Pacific, and genetically engineer some kraken to defend the safe. "Is encryption is only option I have ? I will keep file encrypted & only my app knows how to decrypt" -- many people with the talent to root a device will have the talent to decompile your app, find your encryption algorithm and hard-coded key, and decrypt the file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Carcigenicate, Opiatefuchs all comments appreciated, here is my plan keep file encrypted locally till it gets uploaded to server, once uploaded to server delete local copy. Context.MODE_PRIVATE won't serve my purpose, encryption will make it hard for hacker ( Surely not impossible ) atleast some precaution till file upload happens, thanks

Comment: Yep, that seems a sensible approach. Note that keeping things completely secure locally is very much like the DRM problem. In the end you need some kind of information from outside the system or hardware protection to completely secure your file. Use TLS when uploading and don't forget to *wipe* your data.

Comment: @pcj you got any solution?

Comment: You also have to consider, that "your App" might have been replaced by the User. Also any communication could be intercepted by the user or any third party. Eventually you'll have to accept that you cannot have secrets when running on a user's device.

Comment: @RanjithKumar We couldn't find a way to securely store a file on the phone, we ended up using public/private encryption, Our server generates encryption keys for each user. Public key was sent to mobile on login. Any new file generated on phone were encrypted with the public key then uploaded to the server. Then Server on-demand decrypts the file using the private key. The private key never leaves the server. The assumption here is that server is well fortified behind the firewall. There are third-party services that can help to manage such keys, e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/kms

Comment: @pcj so we can able to encrypt a file(Image,pdf,video etc..) in Android??

Comment: @RanjithKumar We can encrypt but there are some challenges, 1. Handling of large files ( You shall make use of streams, ), 2. The server should render the decrypted files to the client there also make use of streams ( Large files cause memory issues on device ) 3. Delete uploaded & unused files from device ( As encrypted version is already on server ) 4. Do not send private key to device, Do encryption on device ( Using public key ) & decryption on server ( Using private key ), This is what we did

Comment: @RanjithKumar just for reading https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography, Thanks

Comment: @pcj thanks for some useful info

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, encrypting your files seems like a good defense against unbidden access to your data.

Android offers you a range of tools to safely encrypt and decrypt your data:

- [Biometrics API](https://source.android.com/security/biometric) is ideal if you would like to **protect data using the user's biometric characteristics** (such as fingerprints, or iris scans (the different biometric characteristics come with different level of security, at the moment)). Using the Biometrics API, you can ask the user for his or her fingerprint/iris. Once the user has authenticated, you can encrypt some data and store the encrypted text (and the cipher initialization vector), instead of the clear text (for example, in your shared preferences, or in a file). See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth) how to use it.
- If you would like to store **cryptographic keys, certificates, or similar PKI-related data** securely, you can use [key stores](https://source.android.com/security/keystore). A key store is an encrypted file, where each entry can be protected by a different password. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) how to use it.

Android offers methods to generate new [key pairs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#GeneratingANewPrivateKey) and [secret keys](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#GeneratingANewSecretKey).

Answer (score 2):

There are some libs that provide Secure Share Pref like [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) that enough to serve your purpose.

Comment: useful info. But the question is store files securely. you have any other option for files??

Comment: Well in that case u want to encrypt your files you can have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography @RanjithKumar

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You cannot, although I see some suggestions for making it slightly more annoying for people to find your secret among the current answers.

Longer answer: [You cannot 100% guarantee the security of any data](https://lifehacker.com/its-no-surprise-anymore-your-data-is-never-safe-onlin-1471858210), but this is ***particularly*** true if it's on a physical device in someone else's hands.

It's also true that APK code itself [isn't all that secure from reverse engineering](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)(link to online apk decompiler).

That being said, you have a *much better* chance of securing data on a server which can only be accessed by authenticated users.

This is probably many levels of overkill, but [Payment Cards Industry (PCI) compliance standards for data handling](https://phoenixnap.com/blog/pci-compliance-checklist) (random link with an overview) might be a good place to start from, and then you can decide for yourself how much security you actually want to implement. These are the data security standards required for payment processors who store payment card numbers(BINs).

There are also a lot of smaller payment processors who outsource the PCI-compliant part of their data handling to companies who already have the infrastructure in place, rather than invest in building to the standard themselves, due to the high requirements.

I know about all this PCI stuff from engineering experience in the FinTech industry. :)

Comment: that's nice @betweenthelines

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mentioned solutions (encryption) , another solution is **Cloud Storage from Firebase** (if you do NOT save files locally and use Firestore cache instead):

https://firebase.google.com/products/storage

If your data can be saved in db (like shared preferences data) its even better to use **Cloud Firestore**:

https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore